# Which of the following statements concerning metric spaces are true?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, examples-counterexamples

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $J$ be an indexing set. Consider a set of the form $S = \{x_j \in X\ |\ j \in J \}$ with the property that $d(x_j,x_k) = 1\ $ for all $j \neq k,\ j,k \in J.$ Which of the following staements are true?

> a. If such a set exists in $X,$ then there exist open sets $\{U_j \}_{j \in J}$ in $X$ such that $U_j \cap U_k = \emptyset\ $ for all $j \neq k,\ j,k \in J.$

> b. There exists such a set $S$ in $\mathcal C [0,1]$ with $J$ being uncountable.

> c. If such a set exists in $X,$ and if $X$ is compact, then $J$ must be finite.

Clearly (a) is true. Just taking $0 \lt \varepsilon \leq \frac 1 2$ we can see that the indexed collection of open sets $\left \{B(x_j, \varepsilon) \right \}_{j \in J}$ has the required property mentioned in option (a).

How do I proceed to prove or disprove (b) and (c)? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for sparing your valuable time for reading.

Comment: Is $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ equipped with the supremum norm?

Comment: @angryvian since nothing is mentioned explicitly about the metric on $\mathcal C[0,1]$ we may assume that $\mathcal C[0,1]$ is equipped with the sup norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b. Assuming that your distance here is $d(f,g)=\sup|f-g|$, then there is no such set. That so because $\mathcal C[0,1]$ is separable; for instance, the set $Q$ of all polynomial functions from $[0,1]$ in $\Bbb R$ with rational coefficients is dense in $\mathcal C[0,1]$. If $J$ existed, for each $j\in J$ there would be an element of $Q$ in $B_{1/2}(j)$. THat's impossible, since those balls don't intersect and there are uncountably many balls.

c. True. If $J$ was infinite, it would have a countable subset. So, we would have a seuence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $X$ such that the distance between any two distinct terms would be equal to $1$. Such a sequence has no Cauchy subsequence and therefore no convergent subsequence.

Comment: You may assume that $\mathcal C[0,1]$ is equipped with sup norm.

Comment: In (c) you have used sequential compactness. Right?

Comment: Yes, I used sequential compactness. And you already have an answer to b. under that extra assumption.

Comment: No. The answer of Kavi Rama Murthy was wrong. As soon as I pointed out the error he deleted that answer.

Comment: @Anacardium Done.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for b): By Wierstsrass Approximation Theorem it follows that  polynomials with rational coefficients are dense in $C[0,1]$. This makes the space separable.

Lemma

If $(X,d) $ is  separable metric space then we cannot have uncountably many points $(x_j)_{j \in J}$ such that the distance between any two of these is $1$.

Proof: Let $(d_n)$ be a countable dense set in $X$. In $B(x_j,\frac1  2)$ there exists one element of the countable dense set. Call it $d_{n_j}$ Then $j \in J \to d_{n_j}$ is a one-to-one map from $J$ into a countable set so $J$ is necessarily countable.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get your point. What I can see is that for any two distinct points $x,x' \in (0,1)$ with $x \lt x'$ we have$$\|f_x - f_{x'}\|_{\infty} = \max \left \{\dfrac {x' - x} {x}, \dfrac {2(x'-x)} {x'} \right \} \lt 1$$ if $x' \neq 2x.$

Comment: For any two number $a,b \in [0,1]$ we have $|a-b\ leq 1$. So $|f_x(t)-f_y(t)| \leq 1$ for all $t$ which means $d(f_x,f_y) \leq 1$. To prove equality we need just one value of $t$ for which $|f_x(t)-f_f(t)|=1$. Can you see that such a number $t$  there exists ? (Consider the case $x<y$ and $y<x$) @Anacardium

Comment: I have checked that already. If you want I can show you my work.

Comment: So your first answer was wrong. Right?

Comment: @Anacardium I am sorry. There was  a mistake in my answer and I have revised it.